# How do I inject an SVG image in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I receive an SVG image from my back-end and I need to inject it into a container:

```
<div class="svg-container" [innerHTML]="svgData"></div>
```

However, it seems that all `<svg>` elements are removed and my container remains empty:

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

I tested with something simple like `<p></p>` and it worked. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Angular 2 documentation:

> Trusting safe values
>
> Sometimes applications genuinely need to include executable code,
>   display an  from some URL, or construct potentially dangerous
>   URLs. To prevent automatic sanitization in any of these situations,
>   you can tell Angular that you inspected a value, checked how it was
>   generated, and made sure it will always be secure. But be careful. If
>   you trust a value that might be malicious, you are introducing a
>   security vulnerability into your application. If in doubt, find a
>   professional security reviewer.
>
> To mark a value as trusted, inject DomSanitizer and call one of the
>   following methods:

```
> bypassSecurityTrustHtml 
> bypassSecurityTrustScript
> bypassSecurityTrustStyle 
> bypassSecurityTrustUrl
> bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
```

> Remember, whether a value is safe
>   depends on context, so choose the right context for your intended use
>   of the value.

Check out more here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

Comment: How do you actually use that `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` ?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I need to `this.svgData = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myReceivedData);` and it worked. Thanks!